# How to add a tool-chain in the output image of openwrt?

Tags: openwrt, gnu-toolchain

When trying to build a external toolchain for the openwrt image developed for raspberry pi.

Toolchain directory '/opt/cross/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu' does not exist.
make[3]: *** [/home/source/build_dir/toolchain-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/wrapper-1/.prepared] Error 1
make[2]:**  [toolchain/wrapper/compile] Error 2
make[1]:  **[/home/source/staging_dir/toolchain-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/stamp/.toolchain_compile] Error 2
make: *** [world] Error 2

How to bring a toolchain in the openwrt output image in any path like the above (/opt/cross/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu).

Answer (score 0):

why not try install gcc into openwrt ?
using 'opkg install gcc'